# Install NLTK on a virtual environment via PIP - Python3 - Windows 64-bit

Tags: python, pip, nltk, virtualenv, python-venv

I am fairly new to NLTK but I went through a few tutorials and the doc in order to install it properly on my virtual environment and use it in a flask app.

I would like then to export the app as a package so I am looking for a way to install NLTK via PIP or from a script without user input.

Could someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:
1. I included `import nltk` to the __ini__.py of my FLASK app and the following to the create_app() class:

```
try:
    os.mkdir('.\\venv\\Lib\\nltk_data')
except:
    pass
nltk.download('words', download_dir='.\\venv\\Lib\\nltk_data')
```

2. I included nltk in the install_require argument of setup in the setup.py of my application:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='flaskr',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
        'nltk',
    ],
)
```

This is the best solution I found. When the app is installed via PIP, the nltk module is installed as well.
And every time the app is launched, the dictionary is updated.